# Чому ми кажемо «на добраніч»?

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Є сталі вирази «на добраніч», «на все добре». Що тут означає «на», чи відомо, яка тут етимологія, як ці вирази з'явилися? Чому ми так кажемо?

Ще є «на добраніч дати» — прощатись з ким-небудь перед сном, бажаючи приємного відпочинку. Але це, схоже, рідко вживають у сучасній мові.